# Como implementar métodos e classes por algum atalho do teclado no visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Preciso implementar métodos e classes "**pelo teclado**" para obter um valor automaticamente.

> 1: Implementar métodos da Interface na classe Inicio:

```
class Inicio : Interface
{

}
```

> 2: Colocar Get e Set automaticamente:

```
private static RichTextBox rtb
{
     Get { return; }
     Set { value = value; }
}
```

Comment: O que quer dizer com "pelo teclado"? Não fez sentido algum isso pra mim.

Comment: Eu não quero implementar o método ou a interface pelo mouse e sim pelo teclado.

Comment: Ainda não está claro seu objetivo. Implementar onde?

Comment: Você está falando da IDE? Se sim qual seria? Eclipse? Android Studio?

Comment: Windows Forms C#

Comment: Eu classifiquei por passos, 1º quero colocar os métodos de uma interface "por algum atalho do teclado" numa classe sem interface. 2º me refiro como vou implementar um método de "escrita e leitura" para cair o valor get e set automaticamente "por algum atalho do teclado". São passos distintos

Comment: Você se refere ao visual studio?

Comment: Sim, é pelo Visual Studio.

Comment: Se digitar "prop" e apertar tab duas vezes o Visual Studio(2012>) escreve automaticamente `public int MyProperty { get; set; }`, deixa o `int` selecionado para você escrever o tipo que quiser, com mais um tab ele vai para o nome da variável. É isso que quer ?

Comment: Sim, como posso fazer agora na classe que herda a interface?

Comment: Eu pequisei bastante, mas não encontrei nada relacionado via atalho do teclado que funcione, sem ser o `CTRL + .` . Tem uma opção, porém não consegui fazer funcionar. `Visual Studio 2017 > "Ferramentas" > "Opções" > "Ambiente" > "Teclado"`, agora no campo `"Usar o novo atalho em:"` escolha `"Editor de texto"`, no campo `"Mostrar comandos que contenham:"` selecione `"Projeto.ImplementarInterface"`. Adicione as teclas de atalho que deseja e teste. Referência adaptada [link](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/463207-shortcut-key-implement-interface)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que o Visual Studio proporciona para você, são os *[Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms165392.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*.

Com esse recurso, você é capaz de criar vários tipos diferentes de trecho de código.

Dentro do escopo de uma classe, ao ativar o *Code Completion*, você pode filtrar todos os *snippets* disponíveis.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um que utilizo bastante é o `ctor` que cria um construtor para a classe.

Para a implementação de uma propriedade completa, você pode utilizar o `propfull`. Que ele criará a seguinte implementação para você:

```
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}
```

Para utilizar o *Snippet*, você pode digitar ele normalmente e após apertar *Tab* no seu teclado.

Não existe mágica, alguma coisa você vai ter digitar para poder utilizar os recursos que aceleram o desenvolvimento.

Outro recurso interessante que pode lhe auxiliar bastante, é o *[Quick Actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions)*, que pode ser acionado com o atalho `Ctrl+.`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]